# Using a theorem (cycles/permutations)

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $a$ be a permutation of a finite set. Then $a$ can be written as disjoint cycles and $\operatorname{ord(a)}$ is the least common multiple of the lengths of disjoint cycles.

Let $b = (b_1, b_2,\ldots,b_n)$. If $\operatorname{ord(b)}$ is odd, then $n$ is odd by the theorem above.

Since $\operatorname{ord(b)} = n, b^n = e$ so that $\operatorname{ord(b)} \mid n$ and since $\operatorname{ord(b)}$ is odd, $n$ must be odd. But how do we apply the given theorem here? Probably, $b$ has to be written as a product of disjoint cycles first, but how do we do that?

Comment: You first said $\operatorname{ord}(b) = n$, and then conclude $\operatorname{ord}(b) \mid n$, and "since $\operatorname{ord}(b)$ is odd, $n$ must be odd."  This is too complicated.  If $\operatorname{ord}(b)$ is the same thing as $n$, yes one is odd if the other is odd.  However it is not true that $n$ must be odd simply because it has an odd divisor.

Comment: @hardmath, thanks. how do we deduce $\operatorname{ord(b)}$ is odd $\implies n$ is odd from the given theorem?

Comment: Didn't you define $n$ as simply the order of permutation $b$? If I understand your notation, $b$ is a single cycle of length $n$, which explains why it has order $n$. Of course if you are not saying $b$ is a single (disjoint) cycle of length $n$, then the notation needs to be explained.

Comment: @hardmath, let me link the question/answer in my book as they actually are. The part where i define $n$ was an attempt at explaining (to myself) what my book is saying. So, [Question/Solution](http://s14.postimg.org/x6ssf47yp/cycle.png), [The theorem](http://s21.postimg.org/g5989z0dz/theorem.png).

Comment: Do you have a question to ask here? As I said, $b$ is already written as one cycle.

Comment: The second sentence in the solution reads "Since $\operatorname{ord(a)}$ is odd, $n$ is odd by theorem $1.2.20$". How did they deduce the parity of $n$ from the parity of $\operatorname{ord(a)}$ using the given theorem?

Comment: @hardmath, ok thanks.